How to find the minimum set of members of many sets
Given many sets, what algorithm finds the minimum set(s) of members present in all those sets?
For example, given these sets:
{1,2}
{1,2,44}
{2,5,6}
{5,6}

The minimum set(s) of members are:
{1,5}
{1,6}
{2,5}
{2,6}

The problem is similar to Set Cover, except I want to cover the sets and not the elements.

Do you want all such minimum sets or only getting any one them suffices?

I want all such minimum sets. So, if the minimum set size is 2, I want all minimum sets of size 2.

Let $\mathcal{U} = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be the universe and $\mathcal{S} = \{S_1,\dots, S_m\}$ be the collection of sets such that $\mathcal{U} := \bigcup_{j=1}^m S_j$.
Getting one minimum cover set:
Take a collection of singleton sets $s_1,\dots,s_n$ where $s_i = \{e_i\}~\forall i=1,\dots,n$. We need to take the minimum of these singleton sets to cover $\mathcal{S}$. Now consider any solution strategy for the classical set-cover problem (note that it is NP-hard as well as APX-hard). Here, we just need to patch the element covering condition to meet our needs. Note that, when we take $s_i$ into our solution, then all $S_j$ containing $e_i$ is covered. This will give us one of the minimum sized covers.
Getting all minimum cover sets:
We make two key observations here. First, all minimum size covers are of the same cardinality, say $k$. Second, any such cover would, of course, be a subset of $\mathcal{U}$. Thus, there can be at most $n\choose k$ solutions. We can certainly evaluate all of them. We may not need to bother with optimizing this step (which can very well be exponential in $n$) since comutational time for finding one solution (which is NP-hard) would anyway dominate this step.
